# AWS sdk file renaming android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Can we rename a file or folder in AWS(Amazon web services) sdk for android??

I have successfully implemented many features like upload,edit,delete,share file/folder,but I am not getting any docs about renaming a file or folder.

Any link or doc will be helpful.

Comment: please provide more information , are you talking about s3 service ?

Comment: thank you for your reply.Yes I am talking about s3 service.please see this:   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Amazon S3** is a cloud-based object storage system. It is highly scalable and resilient, and processes over 1.5 million transactions per second worldwide. In exchange for operating at such scale, there are some attributes of Amazon S3 that make it **different to a standard file system**, such as:

- It is a flat storage space and **does not support directories**
- It provides **directory-like structures** known as **[Common Prefixes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html)**, which act like directories (for example, it is possible to list all objects with a common prefix, which is effectively the same as listing files in a directory)
- The **key** of an object (analogous to a filename) actually contains the **full path of the object**

For example, object `foo.jpg` stored in directory `cheese` actually has a key of: `cheese/foo.jpg`

This also means that:

- **Objects cannot be renamed.** Instead, objects can be **copied to a new key** and the original deleted.
- **Directories cannot be renamed** because they don't actually exist. Renaming a directory would actually involve renaming all objects "within" the directory. There is no limit on the number of objects stored in S3, so this could potentially involve renaming millions of objects.

Therefore, there are no commands to rename a file ("object") or folder ("common prefix"). Use the [`copyObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#copyObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [`deleteObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#deleteObject(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) functions instead.